# How to calculate execution time (speedup)

Tags: performance, math, cpu-architecture

I was stuck when trying to calculate for the speedup. So the question given was:

---

**Question 1**

*If 50% of a program is enhanced by 2 times and the rest 50% is enhanced by 4 times then what is the overall speedup due to the enhancements? Hints: Consider that the execution time of program in the machine before enhancement (without enhancement) is T. Then find the total execution time after the enhancements, T'. The speedup is T/T'.*

---

The only thing I know is speedup = execution time before enhancement/execution time after enhancement. So can I assume the answer is:

Speedup = T/((50/100x1/2) + (50/100x1/4))

Total execution time after the enhancement = T + speedup

(50/100x1/2) because 50% was enhanced by 2 times and same goes to the 4 times.

---

**Question 2**

*Let us hypothetically imagine that the execution of (2/3)rd of a program could be made to run infinitely fast by some kind of improvement/enhancement in the design of a processor. Then how many times the enhanced processor will run faster compared with the un-enhanced (original) machine?*

Can I assume that it is 150 times faster as 100/(2/3) = 150

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with question 1.

The total time is the sum of the times for the two halves:

```
T = T1 + T2
```

Then, `T1` is enhanced by a factor of two. `T2` is improved by a factor of 4:

```
T' = T1' + T2'
   = T1 / 2 + T2 / 4
```

We know that both `T1` and `T2` are 50% of `T`. So:

```
T' = 0.5 * T / 2 + 0.5 * T / 4
   = 1/4 * T + 1/8 * T
   = 3/8 * T
```

The speed-up is

```
T / T' = T / (3/8 T) = 8/3
```

Question two can be solved similarly:

```
T' = T1' + T2'
```

`T1'` is reduced to 0. `T2` is the remaining 1/3 of `T`.

```
T' = 1/3 T
```

The speed-up is

```
T / T' = 3
```

Hence, the program is three times as fast as before (or two times faster).

Comment: Hey one more question, how the result of this analysis in accordance with Amdahl's Law? I know Amdahl's law is a situation whereby speedup via parallelism is limited by that component of an application which cannot be enhanced. How do we imply in this situation?

Comment: That's basically the second question. The second component (`T2`) is (or can) not enhanced. If you can enhance all other components infinitely, you still are limited to the speed-up of 3.

Comment: Alright thank you so much! I guess I need to spend more time on this.